# What are the interest of the moments of a random variable?

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ a random variable. We define the moment of order $r\in\mathbb N$ by $m_r=\mathbb E[X^r]$. I know that the moment of order $1$ is the expectation, of order 2, one can get the variance, of order 3 and 4, they can be interesting, but in what moments of order $r$ is interesting ? Also, we define the moment generating function by $M_X(t)=\mathbb E[e^{tX}]$. Why such a definition, and not simply $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty m_rx^r\ \ ?$$
(normally, the moment generating function of a sequence $(u_n)$ is $f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}u_nt^n$). Also, what is the interest of the moment generating function ? I really don't see why it's interesting (instead maybe of the fact that $M_X^{(r)}(0)=m_r.$)

Comment: You are underestimating the usefulness of that last mentioned fact imo. MGFs (and CFs) can even be used to recover the distribution in some cases!

Comment: The mgf's derivatives give the moments, hence the name. Your proposed alternative is the typically less useful $\Bbb E\frac{1}{1-xX}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but in what moments of order r is interesting?

One example: in statistics, moments of higher order may be needed in the [method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)).

> Why such a definition, and not simply ...

The moment generating function of a random variable is not defined merely for calculating the moments of a random variable. It has other [important properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Linear_combination_of_independent_random_variables) such as $\phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X\phi_Y(t)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. (Maybe) most importantly, it characterizes a distribution!

Even in the studies of infinite sequences, [exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)) may be generally more convenient than ordinary generating functions in [some situations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerative_combinatorics).

> ... what is the interest of the moment generating function?

You could first read the Wikipedia article on [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function). Again, this is not simply a tool for calculating moments. You may also want to take a look at a more often used cousin: the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), which is essentially the Fourier transform of a random variable. A classical proof the central limit theorem uses the notion of characteristic functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw the wiki article. They wrote for example that if $M_X(t)=M_Y(t)$ for all $t$, then $X$ and $Y$ has the same law. So why considering the Characteristic function instead of moment generating function since both looks to have have the property $M_X=M_Y$ implies $X\sim Y$.

Comment: @user623855: in short: characteristic functions always exist for $L^1$ random varaibles. However, the moment generating function doesn't need to exist because in particular it requires the existence of moments of any order.